# Вопросы по потокобезопасности коллекций и объектов

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, производительность

1. Задача такова, что мне необходимо, чтобы множество потоков проходили по коллекции для сравнения значений. Наполнение коллекции должно будет происходить до операции чтения потоками. Требуется ли для этого в момент чтения делать блокировку lock для обычного списка List? Как можно решить данную задачу не используя lock и какая коллекция для этого подойдет?
2. В пространстве Concurrent имеется список BlockingCollection.Он используется для безопасного добавления и чтения со встроенной блокировкой?
3. Когда требуется чтение свойства объекта из множества потоков ссылочного типа или элементарного, то нужно ли делать блокировки? И нужно ли делать это в случае чтения потоками поля?

Comment: В многопоточном программировании нет общего решения на все случаи жизни. Расскажите, кто и из каких потоков будет читать вашу коллекцию, и какие вашему коду нужны гарантии.

Comment: 1) Никто кроме вас не знает. Но попробуйте concurrentbag. 2) нет 3) никто не знает, кроме вас